# React Button with onClick HTTP request / output as alert window

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make a http get request when clicking on a button.
And also want to see the json data / or converted as a string as output for example in an alert window.

```
// async function
          async fetchAsync () {
            // await response of fetch call
            let response = await fetch('https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=ETH&buyToken=DAI&sellAmount=1000000000000000000');
            // only proceed once promise is resolved
            let data = await response.json();
            // only proceed once second promise is resolved
            return JSON.stringify(data);
          }


buttonEvent(){
             alert(

            this.fetchAsync()
              .then(data => alert(data))
              .catch(reason => console.log(reason.message))

             );
          }

        
          render() {
                return (
                  
                  
                    <button onClick = {this.buttonEvent}>Close Position</button>
)
}
}
```

Above you can see the code of the button component.
When i click the button in the app i get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchAsync' of undefined"

How can i display the values from the http request in my app?

Comment: sorry to not make it clear but the function is defined inside a class component !
So the function fetchAsync is inside Button class component.

Answer (score 0):

you should bind `fetchAsync` function if you don't make them bind automatically.

you can bind the function in `constructor`

this is an example

```js
class Example {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.fetchAsync = this.fetchAsync.bind(this)
  }

  async fetchAsync () {
    // ... do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to using **this** keyword, because you have a function component and **fetchAsync** method is out of your component.

just do like this:

```js
fetchAsync()
```

instead of this:

```js
this.fetchAsync()
```

Also in function component you dont need to call render() method.
render method is for class component;
you can return your jsx template directly with return!
consider that function components are javascript functions!

Your code after correction:

```
async fetchAsync () {
    let response = await fetch('https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=ETH&buyToken=DAI&sellAmount=1000000000000000000');
    let data = await response.json();
    return JSON.stringify(data);
}


function ButtonEvent() {
    function buttonEvent() {
        fetchAsync()
        .then(data => alert(data))
        .catch(reason => console.log(reason.message))
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={buttonEvent}>Close Position</button>
    )
}

export default ButtonEvent;
```

- 

---

**Class Component Version:**

If you want to write it as a class component you should do like this:

```
class MyComponent {

    constructor() {
        this.buttonEvent = this.buttonEvent.bind(this);
    }

    async fetchAsync () {
        let response = await fetch('https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=ETH&buyToken=DAI&sellAmount=1000000000000000000');
        let data = await response.json();
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    }


    buttonEvent() {
        this.fetchAsync()
        .then(data => alert(data))
        .catch(reason => console.log(reason.message))
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.buttonEvent}>Close Position</button>
        );
    }
    
}
```

**Note:** in class component you need to binding this in constructor function :)

Comment: sorry to not make it clear but the function is defined inside a class component i edit the code so its clear
thanks for your asap answer tho!

Comment: how would this be if all is inside a class component ?

Comment: thank you ! :) 

But now i get this (its not even loading the dapp so i cant even see or click the button):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'buttonEvent' of undefined